# moving UIScrollView on rotate on the ipad

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation, uiview, xcode4

I have a multiview application and i have built a custom panelview controller to display panels with limited information about a product, the problem is that there should be 3 panels in portrait aspect and 4 in landscape.

Due to the depth of view controllers (about 5) the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` event will not trigger on the child viewcontroller so i am using the `NSNotificationCenter` on the rootViewController to post a message and picking it up with the child controller.

I can move the panels (UIScrollViews) without trouble but they move into place when i want them to but they move instantly which isn't smooth or tidy, i want them to slide into their new location.

After some searching i am still having no luck finding out how to do this.

```
-(void) updatePanelLocations{
    int buttonWidth = 230;
    int buttonHeight = 335;
    float frameWidth = mainPanel.frame.size.width;
    int numberOfcolumns = frameWidth / buttonWidth;
    float margin = (frameWidth - (numberOfcolumns * buttonWidth)) / (numberOfcolumns +1);
    int currentRow = 0;
    int currentColumn = 0;

    CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
    [animation setDelegate:self];
    [animation setType:kCATransitionReveal];
    [animation setDuration:0.4];
    [animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];

    int i = 0;

    for (UIView* curView in [mainPanel subviews]) {
        //set an arbutrary tag field in generating the scrollviews so i can detect this
        if (curView.tag != 9991) continue;
        //newline detection
        if (currentColumn == numberOfcolumns){
            currentRow++;
            currentColumn = 0;
        }

        [[curView layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"]; 

        //XY Coordinates
        int buttonX = (margin * (currentColumn + 1)) + (buttonWidth * currentColumn);
        int buttonY = (margin * (currentRow + 1)) + (buttonHeight * currentRow);

        //make the frame
        [curView setFrame:CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];        
        [curView setAutoresizingMask: UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];
        //put the button on the target uiscrollview
        [[curView layer] removeAnimationForKey:@"transitionViewAnimation"];
        //next column
        currentColumn++;

        i++;
    }

    animation = nil;
}
```

How can animate this movement for sliding from a to b??

Or better still if i have it all wrong, point me in the right direction :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `UIView`'s `animateWithDuration:` methods.

You'll get the appropriate duration from `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` in the view controller.

Comment: Thats awesome, and really tidy, my method has shrunk somewhat. Thank you.